# SSH fails often when contacting VM from remote machine

Tags: ssh, virtualization, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows 8.1 Host in which I installed ubuntu server 15.05 in a virtual machine. I set an SSH server in the guest (ubuntu) and then I create a forwarding rule from the host port 2222 to the guest port 22.

If I try to ssh from the Host using `ssh -p 2222 username@localhost` I can connect with no problems to the vm.

If I attempt to connect from a remote machine (an OS X one) in the same local network with `ssh -p 2222 username@192.168.X.X` most of the times I get a Timeout error. When I actually manage to establish a connection, after some time it freezes until I get the error *Write failed: Broken pipe*.

I have disabled the firewall of my anti virus (Bitdefender) and created rules in the Windows firewall to allow traffic from the ports 22 and 2222. The problem persists even after disabling both firewalls (Actually, bitdefender's is always deactivated).

I also set `UseDNS no` in the guest's `sshd_config` file. There's no firewall installed in the Guest (ubuntu).

I see the problem happen with both vmware workstation 11 and VirtuaBox.

Comment: How (where) did you set the forwarding rule?

Comment: Is iptables enabled on the VM? Is port 22 "open"?

Comment: @SilvioMassina I use the facilities of both vmware and virtualbox, basically add a rule in the NAT using the networking advance programs of both.

Comment: @Oldskool Yes it is, otherwise I wouldn't be able to connect from the host.

Comment: I don't know what exactly solve the problem but restarting the Host seemed to have fixed my woes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the VM network is not reachable from outside the Windows 8.1 machine. You can see that it works when you ssh to localhost:2222 and that may be caused because of the network configuration (probably is configured as NAT, the default)

When using VirtualBox you should configure the network of the VM to be bridged and that should do the trick. You may get more info from https://superuser.com/questions/810097/vmware-player-bridged-networking-no-longer-works-host-win8-1-guest-mint-17-l

Comment: I can ssh from the remote machine too, it just fails most of the time, and when it doesn't fail, the connection is not stable. But certainly i can connect.

Comment: Then you could enable debug mode adding to /etc/ssh/sshd_config' the line "LogLevel DEBUG" and restarting sshd (e.g. systemctl restart sshd.service), then you can view the logs to see what may be causing those disconnections, although it seems like network issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 7 host with WMware Workstation 12.5.9. The only solution that really helped me:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/590825

Setting alternate QoS flags seems to work around the issue, 
e.g. `ssh -o IPQoS=throughput ...`